# Getting Hibernate to create a TIMESTAMP column

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, kotlin

I am using Hibernate 5.2.14 through Spring Boot 2.0 with MySQL 5.7.20.
I am letting Hibernate generate my Schema (`ddl-auto=update`, I am aware to only use this during development phase) and I am unable to make Hibernate generate a `TIMESTAMP` column in the Schema. Things I have tried (in Kotlin):

```
@Column
var modifiedAt: Instant?

@Column
@Type(type = "timestamp")
var modifiedAt: Instant?

@Column
@Type(type = "Instant")
var modifiedAt: Instant?

@Column
@Temporal(TIMESTAMP)
var modifiedAt: Date?

@Column
@Type(type = "timestamp")
var modifiedAt: Date?
```

All these generate a `DATETIME` column in the database. How do I instruct Hibernate to create a `TIMESTAMP` column? I am aware I could use `columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP"`, however this is just ramming raw SQL down Hibernate's throat, which seems wrong. Is it really the only way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out the Hibernate people are much smarter than me and actually read the MySQL documentation-
As it also turns out, `TIMESTAMP` in MySQL sucks, mostly for being 32-Bit and therefor susceptible to the year-2038-bug. `DATETIME` is therefor the lesser evil and you just need to make sure to store everything in UTC.

Link to Hibernate Forums: https://discourse.hibernate.org/t/why-does-hibernate-orm-uses-datetime-by-default-on-mysql-instead-of-timestamp/422

Answer (score 0):

This is how I handle create and update timestamps.

```
@Column(nullable = false)
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
var created: Date = Date()

@Column(nullable = false)
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
var modified: Date = Date()

@PreUpdate
protected fun onUpdate() {
    this.modified = Date()
}
```

Comment: You can see in my question that I already tried the `java.util.Date` + `TemporalType.TIMESTAMP` combination. Hibernate generates a `DATETIME` column for this as well.

Comment: It does, but it doesn't update the timestamp, that's what the `@PreUpdate` snippet is for; that will update the timestamp of the modified field every time you persist or merge the entity.

Comment: I know how `PreUpdate` and friends work. That is not my problem. I want a `TIMESTAMP` column, not `DATETIME`. `DATETIME` is something completely different and not at all the correct type to use for `TemporalType.TIMESTAMP`.